# PHP URL include not working

Tags: php, php-include

I have a problem with an URL-include, which I don't understand...:
For testing I have coded the following script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "First text";
include("http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.de/includetest.php");
echo "Second text"; 
?>
```

Allow_url_include is set to on. (via php.ini)

Allor_url_fopen ist set to on. (via php.ini)

The includetest.php only contains plain text for testing. There is no php-code.

The result of that script is only the "first text". After that the script is stopped.

If I use "or die('not working');" after the include, the result is the whole text (also the second text) with the following warning:

> Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /srv2/www/htdocs/xhtml-test/_baustelle/testphp02.php on line 6
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening '1' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /srv2/www/htdocs/xhtml-test/_baustelle/testphp02.php on line 6

Why is that? I am at a loss...

Comment: For `or die` to work you need to use proper grouping: `(include '..') or die(..)`, otherwise precedence will cause a different interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full URL not working with php include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369529/full-url-not-working-with-php-include)

Comment: The problem is not the "or die". The problem is the stopping of the script.

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't help me. sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem of code:

```
// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

**Ref. of this [Is Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**

The file you are including is not a valid php file as it is already surved by a server as php.

This code should work as you want:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "First text";
echo file_get_contents("http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.de/includetest.php");
echo "Second text"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @masum-nishat
file_get_contents works, that's right.
but my code (with include) works also at many other clients. only at the one client it doesn't work.
i guess that's a problem with the server. but what?

Comment: I dont know what is going on. But you can check something: 1. site is on `http` or `https` 2. Manually check availability of url, 3. Try connecting some other url and see the error log. hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You should use Relative paths in PHP [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function.

```
include '/path/to/file.php';  // You can include file by relative path
```

As per documentation,

**include through HTTP**

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file
>   to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
>   Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a
>   local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP
>   code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request
>   string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same
>   thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's
>   variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server
>   and the result is then being included into the local script.

```
/* This example assumes that www.example.com is configured to parse .php
* files and not .txt files. Also, 'Works' here means that the variables
* $foo and $bar are available within the included file. */

// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
include 'file.txt';  // Works.
include 'file.php';  // Works.
```

**Warning**

> Security warning
>
> Remote file may be processed at the remote server (depending on the
>   file extension and the fact if the remote server runs PHP or not) but
>   it still has to produce a valid PHP script because it will be
>   processed at the local server. If the file from the remote server
>   should be processed there and outputted only, readfile() is much
>   better function to use. Otherwise, special care should be taken to
>   secure the remote script to produce a valid and desired code.

Here is understanding of Paths.

**1) Relative Paths**

```
index.html
/graphics/image.png
/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

**2) Absolute Paths**

```
http://www.mysite1.com
http://www.mysite2.com/graphics/image.png
http://www.mysite3.com/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

**The first difference** you'll notice between the two different types of links is that absolute paths always include the domain name of the website, including http://www., whereas relative links only point to a file or a file path. When a user clicks a relative link, the browser takes them to that location on the current site.

For that reason, you can only use **relative links** when linking to pages or files within your site, and you must use **absolute links** if you're linking to a location on another website.

For more information, Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript) also.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Yes, I can use absolute paths in include functions. for using http-includes it is necessary to set the allow_url_include attribute to on. and this is done!
My script works at many other sites. But in this one case at this one customer it doesn't work.

Comment: @Julian: Yes. But in some case. Please see example I have included in answer.