# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function?

Tags: php, function, undefined, web-hosting

So i have a problem with my website when im hosting it on my webhost.
i get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function getSkillIcons()
```

The weird thing is that locally(Xampp) it works just fine.

This is how i included the function(in index.php):

```
<?php include 'http://sub.website.com/incl/Settings.php'; ?>
```

this is where i call it (index.php):

```
<div class="panel-body" style="text-align:center">
<?php getSkillIcons(explode(',', skills)); ?>
</div>
```

This how i defined skills (settings.php)

```
define("skills", "Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4");
```

this is the function itself: (settings.php)

```
function getSkillIcons($skills) {
    echo '<a href="?skill=Overall" title="Overall" data-toggle="tooltip"            data-placement="top"><img src="http://sub.website.com/incl/img/skill_icons/Overall-icon.png" class="skill-icon"></a>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($skills); $i++) {
        $tooltip = 'title="'.$skills[$i].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"';
        echo '<a href="?skill='.$skills[$i].'" '.$tooltip.'><img src="http://sub.website.com/incl/img/skill_icons/'.$skills[$i].'-icon.png" class="skill-icon"></a>';
    }
```

Comment: I don't think include over http is possible here. But if you insist to do so, you probably need to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369529/full-url-not-working-with-php-include

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call to undefined function error clearly shows that its not getting your function where you have defined. Reason is you are attaching full path of `settings.php` file with `http`.

You need to include `settings.php` file without `http` path at the top of 'index.php' and make sure `settings.php` file is located in your project only. If it is located at the same folder with `index.php`, then simply include like below.

```
<?php include __DIR__.'/settings.php'; ?>
```

If your `settings.php` file is located in some other folder then you can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to include that file like below:

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/yourpath/settings.php";
include_once($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also just an FYI for anyone trying to call a function within the same class in PHP, refer to the function like below:

```
return $this->doSomething($str);
```