# Call to undefined function printRightContent()

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function **printRightContent** present in **root_directory/lib/common.php  ** in **Adcovate.php** but it gives me the following error error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printRightContent()

This is my PHP file Adcovate.php:

```
<?php
include 'lib/common.php';
function printResults($page, $perpage)
{
?>
<div id="right_content">
        <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('log_errors', 1);
        ini_set('error_log', 'hey_this_errors.log');
        printRightContent();
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

common.php:

```
<?php 
/* Optimize site using GZIP Compression also see .htaccess */
echo "<script>console.log('Common library checkpoint#1' );</script>";
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
<?php
/* dirty code */
define("WEBNAME", "Lawyers.com");
function printRightContent()
{
  echo "<script>console.log('Common library checkpoint#2' );</script>";
  -------somework-----
}?>
```

I have also tried this link : [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492353/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function)

But when I am implementing changes from this link it gives me error:

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

I have tried using adding logs in console using this way:
echo "console.log('Common library checkpoint#1' );";

I am also creating the log file using this way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'hey_this_errors.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to move

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'hey_this_errors.log');
```

at the top of *Adcovate.php* and use

```
require 'lib/common.php';
```

instead of

```
include 'lib/common.php';
```

to verify if *common.php* is really included

Comment: ```
[16-Mar-2023 23:49:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "country" in Advocate.php 
[16-Mar-2023 23:49:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "cat_id" in Advocate.php 
[16-Mar-2023 23:49:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "cid" in Advocate.php 
[16-Mar-2023 23:49:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printRightContent() in Advocate.php 
Stack trace:
#0 Advocate.php .php(293): printResults()
#1 {main}
  thrown in Advocate.php .php on line 528
```

Comment: It seems that *common.php* is included because you don't have any error about it.
Now we have to make sure that we are including the right *common.php*: I suggest you to add at the top of *common.php* in the next row of *<?php* a statement like `die('TADAAAAAH');`
If your program breaks and prints *TADAAAAAH* the include (require) is ok, otherwise  you are including another copy of *common.php*

Comment: yes it is printing TADAAAAAH I guess there is something wrong with the function.

Comment: I'm using same method to debug the issue by placing ```die('TADAAAAAH'); ``` inside the function and realized that function is not being called properly although the spelling matches

Comment: In PHP a function can be conditionally defined wrapping it in an if statement: check if you have omitted something like a semicolon or some other thing that force the function not to be defined (i've seen that you open and close *<?php* tags to print HTML, perhaps there is a mismatch)