# PHP include works but can not call variables or functions within the included file

Tags: php, file, path, include

I am trying to set-up a structure for my application to properly include scripts across various pages and subdirectories

The issue I am having;

inside my index.php I have

```
define ('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/cformv2/');
include BASE_URL . 'inc/functions.php';
require BASE_URL . 'inc/db.php';
include BASE_URL . 'inc/auth.php';
```

and inside my functions.php  I have

```
$hello = 'hi';
```

When I call `echo $hello;` in the index page, it will give me a notice saying;`Notice: Undefined variable: hello in` If I echo $hello in functions page, the message appears in the index page.

After trying to fix, I noticed that, If I move functions.php to the same directory and use `include ('function.php');` and `echo $hello` in the index page, it works. So I assume, I am using this BASE_URL incorrectly.

In summary, what am I trying to do is to be able to include files without manually entering the path each time, after reading a couple of posts, I started using this option using DEFINE ();. Currently, all of my works are in folder cformv2 and working on localhost. Once it finishes, it will be uploaded to my web host. I have multiple files in multiple folders under this base directory (cformv2).

How can define the path to this folder so that I can include my other files from other folders? Also, how it is that I can include the file and not able to call the variable or a function within it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full URL not working with php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369529/full-url-not-working-with-php-include)

Answer (score 0):

You can't open http://localhost/cformv2/inc/functions.php through URL
You can use BASE_DIR as

```
define ('BASE_URL', '/cformv2/');
```

> Include is meant to include and evaluate a specified PHP file. If you fetch it locally, it can be processed like PHP - if you fetch it through a full URL, you will get the resulting HTML (in theory ... you may get only an error).
>   [Full URL not working with php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369529/full-url-not-working-with-php-include)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **include PHP files**, you shouldn't have used URL. There must be full path to file on server, for example:

```
define ('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);
include BASE_DIR . '/inc/functions.php';
```